# валидация телефоного номера

Tags: javascript, form, валидация

написал код для валидации поля - мобильного телефона, но нашёл проблему, при заполнение например 12345 - работает отличтно, 1234п - выдает ошибку, но вот если после буквы поставить снова цифру - 1234п5, то скрип продолжает работать как будто там одни числа, как можно это исправить что можно было вводить только цифры?
html:

```
<div class="form-field">
                        <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
                        <p class="error" id="telError">Это поле обязательное для заполнения</p>
                        <p class="error" id="telErrorTwo">Некорректный ввод</p>
                    </div>
```

Js:

```
document.consaltform.phone.onkeyup = function() {
            var name = document.consaltform.phone.value;
            if (name === "") {
                document.consaltform.phone.removeAttribute("class", "ready");
                document.getElementById("telError").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("telErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("telError").style.display = "none";
                var pattern = new RegExp("[- +()0-9]+$");
                var isValid = this.value.search(pattern) >= 0;

                if (!(isValid)) {
                    document.getElementById("telErrorTwo").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("telErrorTwo").style.display = "none";
                    document.consaltform.phone.setAttribute("class", "ready");
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: смотрите, на данном ресурсе есть поиск https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD и им можно пользоваться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это потому, что ваша регулярка проверяет только окончание значения поля:

```
new RegExp("[- +()0-9]+$")
```

Чтобы тестировать совпадение поля целиком, нужно добавить якорь начала строки:

```
new RegExp("^[- +()0-9]+$")
```

---

Хотелось бы отметить, что это очень слабое выражения для телефона.
Например, вот список валидных номеров:

- `-`
- `----`
- `)-+-(`

Возможно вам следует описать ваше выражение более детально.

Answer (score 0):

Советую обратить внимание на вот этот валидатор. Думаю он решит вашу проблему весьма быстро или хотите все-таки осилить данный скрипт?

https://jqueryvalidation.org/